# The pole, the 15 foot rope, and the donkey 20 feet away

Tags: riddle

A donkey was in a stable, tied by a 15-foot rope to a pole. He then walked 20 feet out of the stable. How is this possible?

Comment: Can we have some punctuation?

Comment: Where the hell was the pole mentioned?

Comment: @Mythi: You seem to have changed the question. The original question never said the donkey was now 20 feet from the stable. It said he was in a stable and he was 20 feet away. These two statements feel very different to me.

Comment: Hmm...sorry then. I should've left it to just punctuation. At the moment, your question will likely be closed for being unclear or having too many possible answers. Please edit it for the meaning you want. People are going to ask "20 feet from what?" though.

Comment: Insecurely. .......

Comment: The lateral thinker in me wants to point out that there is no indication that the rope is tied to anything *but* the donkey, so the pole (which is likely a support to the stable) can be as far away as the donkey walks.  Of course, this is me reading Mythi's edited, slightly more comprehensible version of the riddle.

Comment: @raisinghellyer: Or that the pole isn't secured in the ground, so the donkey can just drag it along with him

Answer (score 3):

> The pole is 5 feet from the stable

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is:

> The pole can be anywhere between a radius of 5 to 15 feet from the stable.

The above condition will allow the donkey to be inside the stable, or be at a distance of 20 feet away from the stable.  (Or even at a max distance of 35 feet from the stable)

Answer (score 0):

It feels like a trivial answer but

> The pole was also 20 feet away, next to the donkey.

Comment: This answer doesn't work--it would not permit the initial configuration (A donkey was in a stable tied to a 15 foot rope).  The pole has to be outside the stable, at least 5 feet but no more than 15 feet away.

Comment: @jscolar: The original question said "A donkey was in a stable he was 20 feet away he was tied to a rope 15 feet long how was he tied to the pole.". I interpreted that as the donkey was in a stable and was 20 feet away from me (20 feet from the stable makes no sense since we just established he was in the stable) amd tied to a rope which was tied to a pole. An attempt to give it better grammar and punctuation changed the meaning significantly.The initial question had a single state that we were asked to explain.